# How do I invoke one Capistrano task from another?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

How do I invoke one Capistrano task from another?

For example:

```
task :foo do
  # stuff
end

task :bar do
  # INVOKE :foo
end
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can do it by using namespace:

```
namespace :test do
  task :one do
  end
  task :two do
    test.one
    #or just directly call it:
    one
  end
end
```

Just be careful with the name you use to not overwrite some important function.

Comment: So why doesn't this work?
`task :d, :roles => [:app] do deploy end`

Comment: A side note: you should not use the `test` namespace as it shadows an existing Capistrano method with that name. You'll get an `ArgumentError` raised.

Comment: yeah sorry for that, it was only example, I have assumed you will pick some more meaningful namespace.

Answer (score 104):

For the record: in the Capistrano 3, use `invoke()`, e.g.

```
desc "Task that does something"
task :do_something do
  invoke 'namespace:task'
end
```

More at https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano#before--after

Comment: just a note: `invoke` must be directly inside the `task`, no `on`, `within` or other blocks. otherwise it won't work.

Comment: How would you reuse a task within a another task's block?

Comment: @aspiringCodeArtisan, one of use cases is creating general task for a series of small ones.

Answer (score 5):

Generally you do this by defining dependencies:

```
before :bar, :foo
```

Answer (score 2):

you also could use `Rake::Task["namespace:task"].invoke`, this works

Answer (score 1):

If the task lives in another namespace, you can use `find_and_execute_task` instead.